# Is installing malicious add-ons via drive-by attacks the only way to add new toolbars to browsers?

Tags: web-browser, malware

Some attacks on web browsers consist in installing new toolbars on the browser of the user (which is just a small aspect of browser-hijacking.
 My question: is installing (malicious) add-ons (via drive-by download attack) the only way to add new toolbars to browsers such as firefox, internet explorer and google chrome ?

Comment: Your title and body do not ask the same question.

Comment: @Stephane Thank you for your remark, but for me i think i expressed the same idea (English is not my mother language, i learnt it by myself)

Comment: I assume you mean aside from the user installing the toolbar him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No

Any attack which compromises your machine could add toolbars to your browser.

However, this is a very different type of attack, and to be honest, any attacker who has full control of your machine is likely to do worse things, like making you part of a botnet, adding keystroke loggers etc.

Comment: Could you list me one attack that leads to install any given random toolbar to a browser ?

Comment: Irrelevant. You asked if it is the only way, and the answer is most definitely no. In my answer I explain why you wouldn't bother, as adding a toolbar is low value compared to total compromise.